# How to use 2 main threads without lags?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In my app, I am using WebSockets and Video streaming.
Playing the live stream on the back view(full screen) and displaying UIViews above it.
I need very reliably to display both of the views(video and UIView block).

When I wrap addSubview into DispatchQueue.main.async {}, my video lags on the very moment when the UIView block appears on the screen.

So based on that, can I somehow separate them into 2 different main threads, so they BOTH can be reliably be displayed on the screen without lagging?

Comment: There's only one main thread. Make sure you're not doing something else that's blocking that main thread.

Answer (score 2):

The lag is likely an indication the UI operation happens in the next runloop even if it wasn't required in the 1st place. What I recommend is following extension:

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    static public func asyncMainIfNeeded(work: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            work()
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            work()
        }
    }
}
```

In comparison to `DispatchQueue.main.async` it will additionally perform a check whether an async main thread dispatch is required at all. Now instead of:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //Your UI operation
}
```

you would do:

```
DispatchQueue.asyncMainIfNeeded {
    //Your UI operation
}
```